# Why doesn't my WPF style work?

Tags: wpf, resources, styles

Trying to put a style in app.xaml. My app.xaml reads:

```
<Application x:Class="TestApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

My XAML for the button is as follows:

```
<Button Content="Click Me!" Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}" />
```

In the designer all looks OK but when I run the code it fails with:

```
Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.
```

I've stared at it for ages but can't spot the problem!

EDIT

It seems to be something to do with the application overall. If I copy my code into another fresh project it works fine. The only difference is that the window is loaded using the "StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml". In the one that doesn't work I load the window up during the App.Startup as follows:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    new TestWindow().Show();
}
```

---

SOLUTION

Found the problem - I was missing an InitializeComponent call. Now the styles work in the final product but not in the designer. I'm going to ask a separate question about it.

Answer (score 6):

Workaround: Just define a Name for the Application object:

> < Application x:Name="App" ...

It worked for me!

Comment: This is fascinating, because it actually works! Any idea why's that? Doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: Ridiculously fascinating!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit: if you've got `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` in the original xaml, but (as your code snippet suggests) you actually have a file called `TestWindow.xaml`, this could be the problem!  Try changing it to `StartupUri="TestWindow.xaml"` in the original project....

Answer (score 0):

You can make a try with {DynamicResource TestStyle}.  Maybe TestStyle is not yet created when you apply it to the Button.

Comment: That runs but then the style is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

usually, in WPF, you want your TargetType to be of the form `{x:Type ...}`
in silverlight, you would use `TargetType="Button"`

Comment: The two are equivalent at runtime. Using x:Type adds some compile time checking.